# Add id to a child of a visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, addition

How can I write in jQuery this:

If `.horse` is visible, then add `#cat` to `.dog` (but only to `.dog` which is child of the visible `.horse`)?

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="horse" style=" margin-right: 20px; display: none;">
    <div style = "width:70%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-20px">
       <div class="rabbit">
           <a class="dog" href="movie.mov"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2" class="horse" style=" margin-right: 20px; display: block;">
    <div style = "width:70%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:-20px">
       <div class="rabbit">
           <a class="dog" href="movie.mov"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#cat').appendTo('.horse:visible')`? - use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

Comment: Did you want to *add the id* `cat` to `.dog`, or *append a separate element* with id `cat` to `.dog`?

Comment: @ZougenMoriver Yeah he/she confused us.. :\

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but it's pretty funny to see how all answers are changed from `.append()` to `.attr()` :)

Comment: @Regent Funny huh.. i left the evidence in my answer.

Comment: I love the semantics of this question... a horse can give birth to a mutant cat-dog! But only when it's a living horse, not a ghost horse. Ghost horses couldn't possibly give birth to a cat-dog.

Answer (score 4):

Use following, it will work

```
$('.horse:visible .dog').attr('id','cat')
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try,</s>

```
$('.horse:visible .dog').append($('#cat'));
```

The above code would append `#cat` into `.dog` which is a descendant of `visible .horse`

If you want to add id to the particular element then do,

```
$('.horse:visible .dog').attr('id','cat');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the ID `cat` to `.dog`, use this:

```
$(".horse:visible .dog").attr("id", "cat");
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rPtL6/)

Answer (score 0):

We can combine [jQuery's `:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) with [jQuery's `attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the `id`:

```
$('.horse:visible .dog').attr('id', 'cat');
```

This will give the `.dog` element contained within your visible `.horse` element an `id` of "cat".